# Find the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n, n+1$ are both 'good' numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

A friend of mine asked me this question from a math Olympiad, and honestly I have no clue on how to solve it. It goes like this: 
A number is called 'good' if the sum of its odd digits is equal to the sum of its even digits (for example, $305224$ is a 'good' number because $3+5 = 0+2+2+4$). Find the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n, n+1$ are both 'good' numbers. 
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: nvm, managed to solve it myself

Comment: What is the digit in the ones place of $n$?

Comment: As this is contest-math, please provide a source, so that we know the problem doesn’t come from an ongoing contest.

Comment: I don't wish to dox myself though, is there another option? Or could I send the source to someone in private?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to observe that the last digit of $n$ have to be $9$. Let's assume that last two digits of $n$ were $a9$, so the last two digits of $n+1$ are $(a+1)9$ if $a \neq 9$. In that case if $a$ was odd the sum od odd numbers changed decreased by $9+a$ and sum of even numbers increased by $a+1$ so $(9+a)-a-1=0$, contradiction, cause $a$ have to be positive. If $a$ was even by the same reasoning we have $9-a-a-1=0$ so $a=4$ and we are looking for for the smallest good number with two last digits $49$.If I'm correct that's $1649$. Case when $a=9$ by similar argument gives as $(18+a)-a-1=0$ or $18-a-a-1=0$ and when number ends with more $9$ it's even worse. So my answer would be $n=1649$, let me know if you catch my drift.

Comment: 1649 is smaller than 12449.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you